# Can't boot after update, stuck on a loop

Tags: boot, kernel

Today I updated my Ubuntu 11.10 to kernel version 3.0.0-16-generic.

After the update I restarted the computer and then I got stuck in a loop right after the initial screen where all the modules are loaded (showing an [OK] text on the right). All I see is the mouse pointer and then it goes back to that screen, and so on.
In some cases, I can see an error that says: `initctl: Event failed`.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance,
Jonathan

Comment: Does booting from a ubuntu livecd work?

Comment: hi, yes, it does. what can i do from the livecd to fix this? thanks!

Comment: The OP solved the problem by reinstalling. So, no answer can be verified whether it worked or not. Hence, I think this question should be closed as "too localized".

Answer (score 2):

Finally I tried a more radical approach: reinstalling ubuntu using a livecd... it took me two attemps, the first one killed my video card, and finally the second one solved all the problems!
Thank you all for your help.
Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

As you mention you can boot from a live cd, you can reset the boot loader manually (which may be part of the problem.)

Boot to the live CD

Determine the block storage device (hard drive partition) of the old system's boot drive, i.e. /dev/sda3 or some such (this is the location of your /boot files in the old system.)  By default, it's on the root partition, you can figure it out by doing in terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /recover
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /recover
ls /recover
```

This is assuming your root or boot drive is on /dev/sda2, it may be on /dev/sda1-?? or /dev/sdb? or /dev/sdc? ; it would really depend on your system.  Assuming it's /dev/sda2...

Terminal:

```
sudo -s
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
chroot /mnt
```

You're now chrooted into your existing system.  Update the system to ensure that the upgrade worked.

```
apt-get update
apt-get full-upgrade
```

then to be sure the boot system is working, run

```
update-grub
grub-install /dev/sda
```

(this assumes your on a single boot system with the disk device /dev/sda with just ubuntu, using grub2 as your boot manager.)

Answer (score 0):

Boot the older kernel. To do so, press and hold shift while booting. Then you'll get to the Grub menu. One of the options is something like "Previous versions". Then select the kernel you used before, and everything should be fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Actually I had already tried that but it didnt work either, i have several kernels in that list and none of them worked.